# Is there a way to pass object to casper.js' evaluate()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I saw this thread and look like there is no way to pass complex object to `evaluate()`
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/casperjs/x7I8LDFwFJ0

So if I write an object and want to share amongst different `evaluate()`, how do I do that?

Let say some silly object like this where I want to use getData function again and again:

```
var testObj = (function() {
  var a = 1;

  function test1(b) {
    return (a+b);
  }

  return {
    getData : function(arg) {
      return (test1(3) + arg);
    }
  }
})();
```

Is there a possible workaround?

**UPDATE 1:**

I mean to pass object with functions. Like below but it doesn't work (return `null`):

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('about:blank', function() {

    var TestObj = function() {
      var a = 1;

      function test1(b) {
        return (a+b);
      }

      return {
        getData : function(arg) {
          return (test1(3) + arg);
        }
      }
    }

    var testObj = new TestObj();

    this.echo(casper.evaluate(function(myObject ) {
        return myObject.getData(100);
    }, testObj));
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't pass a complex structure to evaluate(), because whatever arg passed to evaluate() is sort of JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arg)).

But it doesn't mean that you are not able to pass another kind of objects.

**Example about how pass a JSON Object to evaluate.**

```js
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('about:blank', function() {
    var JSONObject = { arg1: 'val1' , arg2: 'val2' };
    this.echo(casper.evaluate(function(myObject ) {
        return JSON.stringify(myObject);
    }, JSONObject));
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```

**Example about how pass a basic Object to evaluate.**

```js
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('about:blank', function() {

    obj = new Object();
    obj.param1  = "value1";
    obj.param2  = "value2";  

    this.echo(casper.evaluate(function(myObject ) {
        return JSON.stringify(myObject);
    }, obj));
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```

**Example about how pass a function with parameters to evaluate.**

```js
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('about:blank', function() {
    var arg1 = "value1";
    var arg2 = "value2";
    this.echo(casper.evaluate(myFunction, arg1, arg2));
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});

function myFunction(arg1, arg2) {
    return arg1 + "-" + arg2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the the clientScripts option to pass along scripts such as jQuery — [Can i use jQuery with CasperJS](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-use-jquery-with-casperjs). You could probably do the same for custom scripts and have nice separation of code.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: ["includes/jquery.min.js", "lib/my-custom-script.js"]
});
casper.start(function () {
    this.evaluate(function () {
        window.customFunction();
    });
});
```

lib/my-custom-scripts.js:

```
window.customFunction = function () { /* do stuff */ };
```

Hope this helps.